# Selectively populate properties in a SelectMany using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I am using `SelectMany` to do some data transformation. It is essentially flattening some hierarchical data. The problem is that certain related data needs to be represented by the absence of data. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
var records = report.Persons.SelectMany(
            person => person.Relatives.Select(relative => new FlattenedRecord
            {
                ReportNumber = report.ReportNumber,
                ReportDate = report.ReportDate,
                PersonAge = person.Age,
                PersonSex = person.Sex,
                PersonRace = person.Race,
                RelativesAge = relative.Age,
                RelativesSex = relative.Sex,
                RelativesRace = relative.Race,
                Relationship = relative.Relationship)
            }));
```

This results in a list similar to this:

```
ReportNumber|ReportDate|PersonAge|PersonSex|PersonRace|RelativeAge|RelativeSex|RelativeRace|Relationship
           1|2015-01-01|       25|    M    |    W     |    48     |     F     |      W     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|       25|    M    |    W     |    18     |     M     |      W     |   Sibbling
           1|2015-01-01|       25|    M    |    W     |    44     |     M     |      W     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|       14|    F    |    B     |    34     |     F     |      B     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|       16|    M    |    B     |    34     |     F     |      B     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|        8|    M    |    B     |    34     |     F     |      B     |   Parent
```

What needs to happen is if there are multiple persons with the same relative or if a person has multiple relatives then the age, sex, race and relationship data needs to be blank for subsequent lines. Example:

```
ReportNumber|ReportDate|PersonAge|PersonSex|PersonRace|RelativeAge|RelativeSex|RelativeRace|Relationship
           1|2015-01-01|       25|    M    |    W     |    48     |     F     |      W     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|         |         |          |    18     |     M     |      W     |   Sibbling
           1|2015-01-01|         |         |          |    44     |     M     |      W     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|       14|    F    |    B     |    34     |     F     |      B     |   Parent
           1|2015-01-01|       16|    M    |    B     |           |           |            |    
           1|2015-01-01|        8|    M    |    B     |           |           |            |
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do what I need it to do.

Comment: You need to keep some state from one call to the delegate passed to the inner `select` to another. This might be easier with conventional loops (or an iterator). You'll need to specify how to tell that one relative is the same as another.

Comment: @Richard Right now the person objects literally have a reference to the same in-memory Relative object in their Relatives collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Person lastPerson = null;
Relative lastRelative = null;
var records = report.Persons.SelectMany(
    person => person.Relatives.Select(relative =>
    {
        FlattenedRecord r = new FlattenedRecord
        {
            ReportNumber = report.ReportNumber,
            ReportDate = report.ReportDate,
            PersonAge = lastPerson != person ? person.Age : "",
            PersonSex = lastPerson != person ? person.Sex : "",
            PersonRace = lastPerson != person ? person.Race : "",
            RelativesAge = lastRelative != relative ? relative.Age : "",
            RelativesSex = lastRelative != relative ? relative.Sex : "",
            RelativesRace = lastRelative != relative ? relative.Race : "",
            Relationship = lastRelative != relative ? relative.Relationship : ""
        };

        lastPerson = person;
        lastRelative = relative;

        return r;
    }));
```

Comment: Hi @leonardocarreiro, please add some descriptive (text) information about what you are suggesting --- that will make your answer much more effective and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do that instead?

```
var records = report.Persons.SelectMany(
            person => new FlattenedRecord
            {
                ReportNumber = report.ReportNumber,
                PersonRace = person.Race,
                RelativesAge = person.Relatives.Count() > 1 ? null : person.Relatives.First().Age
            });
```